# Are there any sources that disagree with Yitro's advice?

Tags: sources-mekorot, parshanut-torah-comment, parashas-yisro

Are there any sources that disagree with Yitro's advice?

Any sources that say it was detrimental to separate the community from their rebbe? In a way the Rebbe was handing out dollars very day until Yitro came by.

Moshe stood firm against Korach and the Miraglim and here instead of answering to Yitro he calls him 'father in law' which seems to indicate his 'father in law' influence. In other instances Hashem for example says he is against bringing the mixed multitude or tells Moshe 'if he wants to' send the miraglim he may.  Here in the written Torah there is no record of a conversation between Moshe and Hashem.

Could it be that what Korach and the Miraglim failed to do with great rebellion Yitro was able to suggest and influence the Rebbe with barely a consultation with Hashem? Although it is practical advice since when is the Torah practical? Maybe being separated from the Tzadik caused much damage?

It is clear that Yitro teaches us how people can come from far away places and the Torah is accessible to them, just as we were at a very low level. A gentile immerses in a mikva and comes out a Jew - a new creation. But the Mikva does not transform from 40 seah to 41 seah. It is the soul that changes, not the Mikva.

Anyway, if there are any sources that are critical of Yitro's advice please forward. I would be interested to hear what Chazal says.  I cannot find any. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya Yoseph and thanks for this first question. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: Yes, Rabbi David Forhman argues this very forcefully in on of the Aleph Beta paratha videos he produced for Devarim.

Comment: do you have a link for that?

Comment: its ok I found it - interesting

Comment: Forgive me for not knowing where this is, but I just read today in a fort that there’s some pasuk in Devarim in which chazal interpret it to mean that Moshe rebuked Bnei Yisrael for not fighting back on Yitro’s advice as now they no longer were in direct communication with Moshe. Per this rebuke, it would seem the chazal behind it imply there was an aspect of Yitro’s advice that wasn’t so good, i.e. that Moshe was no longer talking to the whole nation anymore individually